# NullPointerException in Nested Loop in Java Cplex

Tags: multidimensional-array, nullpointerexception, nested-loops, cplex

I am trying working on below loop but surprised to get NULLPOINTER EXCEPTION.
It may be i am missing something very minor but i am trying to find this from past some time now...

Code is:

```
for (int a = 0; a < 3; a++) {
        for (int l = 0; l < 3; l++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
                for (int r = 0; r < 3; r++) {
                    for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
                        for (int cc = 0; cc < 3; cc++) {

                            System.out.println("********INSIDE LOOP *testSolution[" + a + "][" + l + "][" + y + "][" + r + "][" + c  + "][" + cc  + "].. " +RezCapCCMulti[a][l][y][r][c][cc]  );
                            /*if( null == Test[a][l][y][r][c][cc]){
                                testSolution[a][l][y][r][c][cc] = 0.0;
                            }else{
                                testSolution[a][l][y][r][c] = cplex.getValues(Test[a][l][y][r][c]);
                            }*/
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
// HERE **Test is of type IloNumVar** and **testSolution is double[][][][][][]**.
Now, i will show some output when executing this.


********INSIDE LOOP *testSolution[0][0][0][0][0][0].. [0.0..1.100011]
********INSIDE LOOP *testSolution[0][0][0][0][0][1].. [0.0..1.100011]
********INSIDE LOOP *testSolution[0][0][0][0][0][2].. [0.0..1.100011]
********INSIDE LOOP *testSolution[0][0][0][0][1][0].. null
********INSIDE LOOP *testSolution[0][0][0][0][1][1].. [0.0..1.100011]
********INSIDE LOOP *testSolution[0][0][0][0][1][2].. [0.0..1.100011]
********INSIDE LOOP *testSolution[0][0][0][0][2][0].. null


Now when i remove comment from IF-Else loop i get NULL POINTER EXCEPTION.

Partial output is shown below,

********INSIDE LOOP *testSolution[0][0][0][0][0][0].. [0.0..1.100011]
********INSIDE LOOP *testSolution[0][0][0][0][0][1].. [0.0..1.100011]
********INSIDE LOOP *testSolution[0][0][0][0][0][2].. [0.0..1.100011]
********INSIDE LOOP *testSolution[0][0][0][0][1][0].. null
Ending cplex session
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at cPlexTest.CplexPrototype.getValues(IOPrototype.java:219) // 219 is this line "testSolution[a][l][y][r][c][cc] = 0.0;"
```

Answer (score 1):

You are checking if Test[a][l][y][r][c][cc] is null:

```
if( null == Test[a][l][y][r][c][cc]){
```

but then you are trying to display the value of

```
Test[a][l][y][r][c]
```

Is it correct? Check the code again or provide the definition of your variables